# AngularJS - Struggling to pass value to factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First i want to say that i'm fairly new to AngularJS, so it might be that i'm asking my question with some oddnes.

I'm trying to pass a string to a factory which in return gives me a result from my database. When i hardcode the values, everything works. But when i try to pass inn values from my view/controller things stop working.

Here is my factory:

```
healthServices.factory('Entry',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:60673/api/hierarchy/:id', { id: '@id'}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true  }
        });
    });
```

Here is the controller im using:

```
$scope.changeData = function (type) {
    $scope.entry = new Entry();
    $scope.id = type;
    $scope.healthData = $scope.entry.$query({ id: $scope.id });
}
```

And this is how it looks in my html:

```
<button ng-click="changeData('someValue')">
```

At the moment i keep getting

> TypeError: value.push is not a function

As i mentioned im quite new to this, so I might be far off. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can't see any .push function called in your code, thus can't help you with that at the moment.

Comment: If you're just looking to get one result from the database, as it appears you are, then you can just use `$scope.entry.$get({ id: $scope.id });`. But as @Erazihel said, you're not showing the code that's triggering the error.

Comment: Can you provide your server response to such request? If it's not returning an array, it may trigger the above error.

Answer (score 1):

What is intended by this line of code?

```
     $scope.entry = new Entry();
```

Entry is your service you want to call.
You should pass this into your controller via dependency injection.
Angular does the 'new' for you.

```
    myApp.controller('myCntrl', HomeCtrl);
    HomeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'Entry'];

    function HomeCtrl($scope, Entry) {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing any wrong with your $resource configuration.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngResource']);

myApp.factory('Entry', function ($resource) {
            return $resource('http://localhost:60673/api/hierarchy/:id', { id: '@id'}, {
                query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true  }
            });
        }); 


myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'Entry', function($scope, Entry){

    $scope.changeData = function (type) {
        $scope.entry = new Entry();
        $scope.id = type;
        $scope.healthData = $scope.entry.$query({ id: $scope.id }); 

    }
}]);
```

i am getting below in console

```
GET http://localhost:60673/api/hierarchy/someValue
```

error lies on other part of the code, please post your controller completely.